# Total duration value should change when new row is added but it doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a text box at top which displays the total duration. Now what happens is the user selects a duration from a timepicker and this will be displayed in the textbox and then add it into a new row. Now the situation I have is that the format of the textbox is like this "00 Hrs 00 Mins 00 Secs".

So for example if the total duration remaining is 01 Hrs 30 Mins 20 Secs and if you select 00 Hrs 40 Mins 00 Secs from the timeicker (you use the timepicker sliders to choose your duration and then click ok and the value is displayed in the textbox) and then add it into a new row, then 01 Hrs 30 Mins 20 Secs should minus 00 Hrs 40 Mins 00 Secs to make 00 Hrs 50 Mins 20 Secs.

Problem is that it is not changing the total duration remaining when I add a row with the duration selected. Does anyone know why this is?

There is no problem with the live() method I am using (even though I will change it to on in the future), I believe the problem is my calculation in the jquery but I am not sure.

Below is the code in fiddle (this does not display the timepicker, this jsfiddle is here to show you what the code looks like and how you can add a new row).

http://jsfiddle.net/7JWVJ/5/

I have one application which is working correctly which is very similar to what I want to do for this application but this uses ordinary numbers in a textbox. This is in the fiddle below. Just open the fiddle and enter in a number in the textbox, click on the "Add" button and it will take away the number you entered from 100. Edit the row you have added to a different number and see the calculation work again. It is normal numbers for fiddle below while the duration has the format "00 Hrs 00 Mins 00 Secs, that is main difference between the two

http://jsfiddle.net/uThKQ/25/

Comment: please add a working code with the timepicker and all so that we can test with it

Comment: Try this link here http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/testing/Testpage.php, it should work. Only difference is var duration is not var duration = "01 Hrs 30 Mins 20 Secs"; but instead var duration = '<?php echo "01 Hrs 30 Mins 20 Secs" ?>'; As duration will be retrieved from a php variable

Comment: so the problem is that the total duration doesn't change, right?

Comment: @redmoon7777 yes that is right, the total duration remaining should change when you select your duration from the timepicker and add it to a new row.

Comment: ok give me a minute to figure it out.

Comment: ok I did it but what do want to happen if time remaining is negative?

Comment: if negative then display it with a minus sign  it from of it e.g. if it is over by 10 minutes then display: - 00 Hrs 10 Mins 00 Secs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok here you go : (the code can use more optimization of course but this works)

```
    var duration = '01 Hrs 30 Mins 20 Secs';



$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#total-duration').html(duration);

    $(function() {  
        $('#questiondurationpicker').trenttimepicker({
            timeFormat:'hh mm ss',
            hourGrid: 4,
            minuteGrid: 10,
            secondGrid: 10,
            showOn: 'button',
            buttonImage: "Images/clock.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true
        });        
    });

    $(".questiondurationpickerRow").live("change", calculateDuration);
    $("#addQuestionBtn").live("click", calculateDuration);
});



function insertQuestion(form) {      
    var $tr = $("<tr></tr>");
    var $duration = $("<td class='duration'></td>");

    $('#questiondurationpicker').each( function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $durationText = $("<input type='text' class='questiondurationpickerRow' readonly='readonly' />").attr('name',$this.attr('name')).attr('value',$this.val())
        $duration.append($durationText);
    });

    $tr.append($duration);
    $('#qandatbl').append($tr);

    $('.questiondurationpickerRow').trenttimepicker({
        timeFormat:'hh mm ss',
        hourGrid: 4,
        minuteGrid: 10,
        secondGrid: 10,
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonImage: "Images/clock.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });
}

var format = duration.match(/(\d\d)/ig),
hours = parseInt(format[0], 10),
mins = parseInt(format[1], 10),
secs = parseInt(format[2], 10);

function calculateDuration()
{
    var totalduration = duration;  
    var sign = '';
    var tmp_hours = 0;
    var tmp_mins = 0;
    var tmp_secs = 0;

    $("#qandatbl td.duration input").each(function (){
        tmp_format = $(this).val().match(/(\d\d)/ig),
        tmp_hours += parseInt(tmp_format[0], 10),
        tmp_mins += parseInt(tmp_format[1], 10),
        tmp_secs += parseInt(tmp_format[2], 10);

    });

    newH = hours - tmp_hours;
    newM = mins - tmp_mins;
    newS = secs - tmp_secs;

    if( newS < 0 ) {
        newS += 60;
        newM--;
    }
    if( newM < 0 ) {
        newM += 60;
        newH--;
    }       

    if(newH < 0) {
        newH = tmp_hours - hours;
        newM = tmp_mins - mins;
        newS = tmp_secs - secs;
        if( newS < 0 ) {
            newS += 60;
            newM--;
        }
        if( newM < 0 ) {
            newM += 60;
            newH--;
        }       
        sign = '- ';
    }       

    checkedH = (newH < 10 ? '0' : '') + newH;
    checkedM = (newM < 10 ? '0' : '') + newM;
    checkedS = (newS < 10 ? '0' : '') + newS;

    new_duration = sign + checkedH + ' Hrs ' + checkedM + ' Mins ' + checkedS + ' Secs';


    $("#total-duration").text(new_duration);

}
```

Comment: there is just one little thing. Lets say total duration is 01 Hrs 30 Mins 20 Secs, and you select 00 Hrs 30 Mins 00 Secs and add the row, then it displays 01 Hrs 00 Mins 20 Secs, which is great, but then if user goes back to top control and select 00 Hrs 20 Mins 00 Secs and adds the row, you will now have two rows, which altogether makes 00 Hrs 50 Mins 00 Secs so total duration should be 00 Hrs 40 Mins 20 Secs. But at moment it is only calculating for the current row you have added so it is only minus the second row 00 Hrs 20 Mins 00 Secs making total duration 01 Hrs 10 Mins 20 Secs

Comment: Perfect :), upvoted answer, best answer and a big thank you for helping me. Anyone who see this answer plz upvote it because it is a great answer.